# How to convert the replace() javascript regex function to actionscript?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

Both JS and AS3 implement RegEx as defined in the ECMAScript edition 3 language specification (ECMA-262).

Although I may not have any trouble converting the regular expressions themselves, in javascript I see the `string.replace()` function used.

[AS3](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/RegExp.html) only has `exec()` and `test()`, are they equivalent to `replace()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.replace()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace()), as you'd expect.

It's a member of the String object, just like in JavaScript. `exec()` and `test()` are members of the RegExp object, just like in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

AS3 has [`String.replace()`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/String.html#replace%28%29) -- the very link you mentioned. Any problems with this function?